# fbx model got 'deviance' at UV seam

Tags: three.js, textures, fbx

When id use FBXLoader to load fbx model,  a seam appeared on the map of the model.
Here the image of fbx model on uv seam:

[image]

Here the texture of the model:

[image]

How to fix this problems?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting that texture's `minFilter` to `THREE.LinearFilter`. This should improve it if not eliminating the seam altogether.

The other solution is of course to add padding to your texture.